# Polymorphism and calls from a module

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I'm having trouble with the use of polymorphism in object oriented programming in python. Here I define a specialisation of the list class that overrides the append and **setitem** methods

```
class MyList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, key,value):
        super(MyList,self).__setitem__(key,value)
        print("bubu")
    def append(self,value):
        super(MyList,self).append(value)
        print("bibi")
```

Now if I test this class with

```
myobj = MyList()
myobj.append(1) 
myobj[0]=3
```

I get "bibi", and then "bubu", as expected. But if I use a MyList object with an external module

```
import heapq
myobj = MyList()
heapq.heappush(myobj,1)
```

The function heappush from heapq is supposed to call myobj.append (I checked the sources https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/heapq.py). But I get no "bibi" this time ! Isn't the "append" called supposed to be that of the instance passed in arguments ?

Where are my bibis ?? :)

Comment: I also observe the same on vanilla 3.8.5. I'm not accustom to debugging in standard library source, but I don't see how the linked source code can be the actual implementation. For example, if I pass a random "heap" parameter of a non-list class, I get the error "*TypeError: heap argument must be a list*" which is not something thrown or guarded for in the given "implementation". Perhaps this source code is a pure reference and not even used in the standard implementation.

Comment: I also tried with copy the source of the function code and paste to the same file which contains MyList class and works well but when you create a separate file (which contains "heappush" function) and used it by import doesn't work well. Very interesting issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run Python without any arguments and enter the following, I am fairly certain you will get no import error:

```py
>>>
>>>
>>> from _heapq import *
>>>
```

I mention this because if you just look a little more deeply into the source code for `heapq`, you will see at the bottom:

```py
# If available, use C implementation
try:
    from _heapq import *
except ImportError:
    pass
... # etc.
```

And since we had no reason to believe your `MyList` implementation of method `append` was not working correctly, that alone should have suggested that the `heapq.heappush` method was *not* calling the `append` method on the list. And now we no why.

**Update**

To load `heapq` without `_heapq`:

```py
import sys
import importlib
import _heapq

 # Make _heapq unloadable
del _heapq
sys.modules['_heapq'] = None

# heapq was already loaded with _heapq; get a reference:
heapq = sys.modules['heapq']
# reload heapq, but this time without _heapq:
importlib.reload(heapq)

class MyList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, key,value):
        super(MyList,self).__setitem__(key,value)
        print("bubu")
    def append(self,value):
        super(MyList,self).append(value)
        print("bibi")

myobj = MyList()
heapq.heappush(myobj,1)
```

Prints:

```None
bibi
bubu
```

Interesting that 'bubu' and 'bibi' print. This is the result of `_siftdown` method that `heappush` finally calls that results in 'bubu'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is there any way for me to force the use of the python implementation rather than the C implementation ?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: This trick completely solves my problem. Many thanks !!

Comment: Yes, but you will have code that runs more slowly, of course. I have just updated the code to simplify it slightly (simpler method than `import heapq` to get a reference to the `heapq` module that is created when `_heapq` is imported).